# css (or jQuery) fade on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, fade

I've been self-teaching myself CSS and Javascript/jQuery lately, however. I'm more the sort that learns from dissecting code that's already there. My current "project" is this: http://jsfiddle.net/wqc42v6p/

I've tried soemthing like this:

```
#Premise {visibility:hidden;}
#Premise:hover {visibility: visibile;}
```

with no results.

I eventually got to thinking if the premise div is hidden, perhaps it's impossible to hover over it. I'm not sure how to make hovering over one div affect the visibility property of another, either. Even if that worked, I imagine then the mouse isn't really hovering over the div with the :hover psuedo... so it might just fade back... or so is my theory. I don't even know. Like I said, I'm self-taught.

I'd also like to have it fade in when the area's hovered over and out when the hover leaves the area.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `opacity:0` And `opacity:1`

http://jsfiddle.net/p289a03w/

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'opacity' instead of 'visibility', and add 'transition' to declare the transition time.

try this:

```
#Premise {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#Premise:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel incredibly stupid. I've found a way that works:

```
#Premise {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s; 

}
#BlightOne:hover > #Premise{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Apologies for the bother.

Comment: Might want to also read up on stacking one div atop another with `z-index` and `position: absolute`.

Comment: I was told it was bad to use absolute positioning. Also, would z-index allow me to fade?